# how take data from xml using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need take value of xml node <СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>201, 201 value.

I try take this value using code below:

C#

```
var attrArr = (_doc.Root.Descendants("Раздел2РасчетПоТарифуДопТарифу")
    .Where(i => i.Descendants("КодСтроки").FirstOrDefault().Value == "201")
    .Select(i => i.Descendants("СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода").FirstOrDefault().Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But I get only first value (201).

If I enter `i => i.Descendants("КодСтроки").FirstOrDefault().Value == "202"`, value = 0

XML

```
<Раздел2РасчетПоТарифуДопТарифу>
        <Раздел2_1_РасчетСВпоТарифу>
          <КодТарифа>03</КодТарифа>
          <НаОбязательноеПенсионноеСтрахование>
            <ВыплатыИвознаграждения_1966старше>
              <КодСтроки>201</КодСтроки>
              <РасчетСумм>
                <СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>201</СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>
                <СуммаПоследние1месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние1месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние2месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние2месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние3месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние3месяц>
              </РасчетСумм>
            </ВыплатыИвознаграждения_1966старше>
            <ВыплатыИвознаграждения_1967моложе>
              <КодСтроки>202</КодСтроки>
              <РасчетСумм>
                <СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>202</СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>
                <СуммаПоследние1месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние1месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние2месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние2месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние3месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние3месяц>
              </РасчетСумм>
            </ВыплатыИвознаграждения_1967моложе>
            <ВыплатыИвознаграждения_ВременноИГ>
              <КодСтроки>203</КодСтроки>
              <РасчетСумм>
                <СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>203</СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода>
                <СуммаПоследние1месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние1месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние2месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние2месяц>
                <СуммаПоследние3месяц>0.00</СуммаПоследние3месяц>
              </РасчетСумм>
```

I need take values 201, 202 and 203

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var attrArr = (_doc.Root.Descendants("Раздел2РасчетПоТарифуДопТарифу")
.Where(i => i.Descendants("КодСтроки").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "202"))
.Select(i => i.Descendants("СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода").FirstOrDefault().Value)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: cannot convert expression  type XElement to return type bool. .Where(i => i.Descendants("КодСтроки").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "202"))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will return 201, 202 and 203

```
string str = ....
var x = XElement.Parse(str);    
var result = x.Descendants("СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода")
   .Select(xx => xx.Value)
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
var xyz = (from item in _doc.Elements("РасчетСумм")
select item.Element("СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода").Value).ToList();
```

It will select the value from the nodes СуммаВсегоСначалаРасчетногоПериода and put it in a list